# If statement not working for some reason

Tags: javascript

Here's my code:

```
alert ("Current: " + crmForm.all.new_currentdate.DataValue);
alert ("Previous value: " + crmForm.all.new_date.DataValue);

if(crmForm.all.new_currentdate.DataValue != crmForm.all.new_date.DataValue )
{
  crmForm.all.new_otherValue.DataValue  = null;
  alert("Nulling other value");
}
```

As you can see, I've put in alerts to check the values at the start, and they are the same. However, it is still going into the IF statement, and the 3rd alert (Nulling other value) gets displayed too. Any ideas? This is in MS Dynamics CRM.

Thanks

Comment: what type of data are those `DataValue`? if they are strings, maybe one of them has some whitespace at the end...

Comment: When you check it in an `alert` box, you can verify their equality only by looking at it, so essentially, it might be that they just look equal, or specifically, their string representations are looking equal (they are converted to strings since you concatenate it with a string). Try the following and see what you get: alert(crmForm.all.new_currentdate.DataValue == crmForm.all.new_data.DataValue)

Comment: Call `trim()` on the two values before comparison, to prevent any whitespaces at the ends causing this.

Comment: I tried alert(crmForm.all.new_currentdate.DataValue == crmForm.all.new_data.DataValue), as suggested by Rohan Prabhu, and got false. They are datetime values. I'll try trim() too, but would that only be effective for string values?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(true + 1); // outputs 2
console.log(true == 1); // outputs true
console.log(true === 1); // outputs false. true is not the number 1. 
console.log(false + 1); // outputs 1
console.log(false == 0); // outputs true
console.log(false === 0); // outputs false. false is not the number 0.
```

for the unitiatated javascript if statements can be rather weird, [from here](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)